# SNS AWS em .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-aws, push-notification

Alguém ja implementou SNS na AWS com C#?

Eu implementei o código abaixo em uma tentativa pelo envio por tópico criado pela console, mas preciso fazer tudo pelo nosso ADM em .net.

Segue o código que eu estou tentando o envio pelo tópico. Não dá erro, mas por algum motivo também não está enviando. Alguém saberia dizer o que esta faltando nele?

```
        RegionEndpoint regionEndPoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
        IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient = 
            AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient("#####","#######", regionEndPoint);

        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest()
        {
            Subject = "teste",
            Message = "{\n\"APNS_SANDBOX\":\"{\\\"aps\\\":{\\\"alert\\\":\\\"'sdfsdfsdfd'\\\"}}\"\n}",
            TopicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:###############",
        };

        snsClient.Publish(publishRequest);
```

Comment: Eu resolvi tinha que dar subscribe nos devices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi tinha que dar subscribe nos devices